# Cocoa: Get frontmost window of active application

Tags: cocoa, macos

How can I get the NSWindow object from the frontmost application? What I'm trying to do is a SizeUp, so from my app I could resize the frontmost window of any app.

Comment: UIWindow is from iPhone, but you tagged this as macosx.  Which platform are you asking about?

Comment: Do you mean NSWindow? UIWindow is iPhone specific, and as of right now, you can only run one application a time until 4.0 is officially released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get an NSWindow from another app.  You might be able to resize a window of another app using accessibility APIs, if the user has enabled access for assistive devices in the Universal Access preferences.